# format rules for mobile tephone numbers auto complete

Tags: regex, phone-number

I'm looking for how to compile rules for each county which specifically determine valid format for mobiles phones (only). For example: the uk country code is 44 and all (mobile) numbers start 07 followed by xxx xxx xxx (nine digits) where x is [0-9]. Mobiles dont have extensions or other so the rule here is very simple. If you are a resident of any other country with certain knowledge or can provide a link to such for your country, could you please reply, I'm afraid it seems unlikely that there is a document or reg ex - as all seem to be for more general phone numbers and therefore a much wider reg ex than I want or need.

Comment: from http://www.regexlib.com I have:  UAE mobile phone numbers. Its capable to take inputs +97150 3827741, +97-150-3827741, +97150 - 3827741,050 3827741, 050 - 3827741: ^(\+97[\s]{0,1}[\-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}1|0)50[\s]{0,1}[\-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}$

Comment: Validator for New Zealand Mobile phone numbers. Will look for the first number being a 0 and must be a number or either 6 or 7 digits long after to initial (021) suffix (^\([0]\d{2}\))(\d{6,7}$)

Comment: Polish Supported: +48 prefix (optional); separating elements with hyphen or space ^(\+48\s+)?\d{3}(\s*|\-)\d{3}(\s*|\-)\d{3}$